# switch languages for globalization tests (win 8 / winjs)

Tags: windows-8, globalization, winjs

I am working on globalization for my Windows 8 app.

Currently i am using **resjson files**, but i can test these only in 1 language. i would like to switch languages.

my filesystem looks like this:

http://www.jonathanantoine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/resourceFolder.png

Please tell me how i can switch languages for testing issues?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

go to control panel, Add language (under Clock, Language and Region). Add all of your languages to this list. In order to switch language, change the order of the languages from this list. Your testing language should be on top.